# Zend framework 2 service locator is null in constructor

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2. To not repeat myself in every action. I wrote getter/setter for the dbAdapter. I want to instantiate the db adapter in the constructor of the controller.
For creating an instance of the db adapter I do

```
$this->getServiceLocator( ) )->get( 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' ) )
```

However if I call this in the constructor, servicelocator will be NULL

```
$this->getServiceLocator( ) )
```

Any way on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Service locator is set after `__construct` method is called. So `$serviceLocator` will never be set at `__construct` time.

Read more on this here

https://juriansluiman.nl/article/139/zf2-why-a-service-is-not-available-in-your-constructor

You need to write a factory for your service rather than just configuring it as an invokable. Use constructor injection.

```
class MyService 
{
    protected $myDependency;

    public function __construct(MyDependency $myDependency)
    {
        $this->myDependency = $myDependency;
    }
}
```

Quickest way is in the appropraite module.php file

```
    public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            'myService' => function($serviceManager) {
                return new MyService($serviceManager->get('myDependency'));
            }
        ]
    ];
}
```